# Extracting Missing values with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to solve the problems of handling missing values using item_loader.add_css in links and critic items. It should be 8 values per item, but it is 6 and doesn't extract anything in critic.

My code is :

rotten_spyder.py

```
class RottenSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'rotten'
    start_urls = ['https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/toy_story/reviews?type=top_critics&sort=&page=2']

    def parse(self, response):
        # crawl page 
        for row in response.css('.content'):

            item_loader = ItemLoader(item=ScraperottentomatoesItem(), selector=row)
            item_loader.add_css('quote', '.the_review::text', re='\w+.+')
            item_loader.add_css('links', '.review-link a::attr(href)')
            item_loader.add_css('critic', '#content .articleLink::text')

            yield item_loader.load_item()
```

items.py

```
class ScraperottentomatoesItem(scrapy.Item):
    quote = scrapy.Field()
    links = scrapy.Field()
    critic = scrapy.Field()
```

Here is the output without critic:

[image]

[image]

Comment: to be more specif. I want to scrape critic, quote, and Full Review. All of them, 8 items per field.

Comment: hi, any suggestions?

Comment: hi, any jedi of code?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you said it should be 8 items. If you look at the website the hyperlink that says "Full Review" is where the link is. There are only 6 links so that is fine. For the second part you are extracting the text instead of the link, so you would change it like the other one.

Here doing this code. It worked for me.

[image: Rotten]

Here's the output:

{'critic': ['Sean P. Means',
            'John Hartl',
            'Peter Stack',
            'Roger Ebert',
            'Rita Kempley',
            'James Berardinelli',
            'Roger Moore'],
 'links': ['http://www.sfgate.com/cgi-bin/article.cgi?f=/c/a/1996/11/01/DD69735.DTL',
           'http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/toy-story-1995',
           'http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/style/longterm/movies/videos/toystory.htm',
           'http://www.reelviews.net/php_review_template.php?identifier=46',
           'http://www.ew.com/ew/article/0,,299671,00.html',
           'http://www.orlandosentinel.com/entertainment/movies/orl-movie-review-toy-story-toy-story-2-3d,0,464068
0.story'],
 'quote': ['Technically, Toy Story is nearly flawless.',
           "Disney's witty, wondrously imaginative, all-computer-generated "
           'cartoon is far and away the best of the new holiday movies in '
           'town.',
           'The script, by Lasseter, Pete Docter, Andrew Stanton and Joe '
           'Ranft, is filled with clever gags that keep the two heroes at each '
           "other's throats and the plot on fast- forward.",
           'The result is a visionary roller-coaster ride of a movie.',
           "It's a nice change of pace to see the studio draw magic from this "
           'modern tale about ordinary 20th-century kid Andy and his '
           'eager-to-please playthings.',
           "The one big negative about Toy Story involves Disney's "
           'overcommercialization.',
           'I can hardly imagine having more fun at the movies than I did at '
           "Toy Story, the miraculous new Disney feature that's the first "
           'full-length animated film to be produced entirely on computer.',
           'The great voice acting, the visual puns, all added up to an '
           'animation game changer.']}

Comment: Hi, I put a comment above to be more specific, a line of code and a image. As for critic, the css   parameter is ok (I did a response.css('#content .articleLink::text').extract() and give a list), but it doesn't any extraction with item_loader. I suppose because there is a missing value in one critic see the picture. Thanks

Comment: I think i fixed it. Please let me know.

Comment: If no value in the review should be count and the code put 'none' (the first two). Similarly, in critic the seven-item. All the lists should contain 8 values on this page to scrape it correctly. The list Critic is still in problem and doesn't export the whole list in JSON file and it doesn't appear on the pycharm debugger. What could be wrong?

Comment: Check the image of the debugger above

Answer (score 0):

If no value in the review should be count and the code put 'none' (the first two). Similarly, in critic the seven-item. All the lists should contain 8 values on this page to scrape it correctly. The list Critic is still in problem and doesn't export the whole list in JSON file and it doesn't appear on the pycharm debugger. Thanks for your help